# Sign of coefficients

Tags: power-series, bernoulli-numbers

Let $a_0,a_1,\dots$ be the sequence satisfying
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1}\right)=1.
$$
This means that $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=-\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{a_j}{n+2-j}$.
One gets $a_1=-\frac12$ and $a_3=-\frac{13}{720}$.

The first and most important question is:
Is it true that all coefficients $a_n$ for $n\ge 1$ are strictly negative?

Secondly, is there any connection to, say, Bernoulli numbers or any other sequence that carries a name?

Comment: I think $a_2=-\frac{1}{12}$, $a_3=-\frac{1}{24}$, $a_4=-\frac{19}{720}$.

Comment: @GH: yes, sorry, untidy notes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These numbers (with alternating signs) are called Bernoulli numbers of the second kind or Cauchy numbers. Two proofs that these numbers are negative can be found in http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/slides/analysis-nec.pdf.

Another reference is

[Merlini, Donatella; Sprugnoli, Renzo; Verri, M. Cecilia,
The Cauchy numbers. 
Discrete Math. 306 (2006), no. 16, 1906–1920.](http://www.dsi.unifi.it/~merlini/papers/Cauchy.pdf)

The determination of the sign of these numbers can be found much earlier in Charles Jordan's 
*Calculus of Finite Differences*, page 267.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A006232 -- if the OP had had tidier notes, he might have found this on his own. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since the second series can be explicitely computed, you have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n = -\frac{x}{\ln(1-x)}.$$ Now you can compute explicitely a recurrence relation giving you the exact value of $a_n$ by computing iterated differentials at $0$ of this analytic function. Or derive explicitely the sign of $a_n$, which I believe to be not too difficult, but I don't have the time right now to do it…

Comment: I knew this equation, I started with it. Computing of iterated differentials didn't help.

Comment: Ok, sorry about my sloppy answer ;)